# Matrix and eigenvalues question hints?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

This is the homework

[image]

I have done part a, b, but I don t have any idea how to do the rest

$y = 5$ and $z = 12 $
Those are the eigenvalues of matrix $A$

For part c, and d, I've tried to put some matrix with values in it and its inverse,but it does not match up with the equation of

$$VDV^{-1} = A $$

Answer (score 1):

V isn’t just any arbitrary matrix. They're trying to take you step by step through the diagonalization process in this exercise, so the eigenvectors that you computed in part b are going to come into play here.